# CSS: layer two elements centered

Tags: css

How can I do this:

1. an image
2. a simple small DIV on top of the image, centered vert/horiz, which doesn't appear until the image is rolled-over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;">
    <img src="path/2/img.png" style="z-index:1;"
         onmouseover="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display='block';">
    <div id="hidden" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:10;"></div>
</div>
```

If it works for you, clean it up before you deploy it! :)

**NOTE:** div#hidden is not yet centered over the image. If you know the width and height of it in advance, you can use this method:

```
#hidden {
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top: -(heightOfHiddenDiv/2)px
    margin-left: -(widthOfHiddenDiv/2)px
}
```

Otherwise you will need to get the computed values of width and height in JavaScript.

Comment: Almost: but the `margin-top` and `margin-left` need to be half the height/width of `#hidden`, not half the height/width of the image.

Answer (score 2):

If you can have a fixed width and height for the `<div>`, then I’d suggest this:

#### HTML

```
<div class="hover_image">
    <img width="250" height="300" src="http://pauldwaite.me.uk/images/professional.jpg" />
    <div class="overlay">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.hover_image {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.hover_image .overlay {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 3em;
    margin: -2em 0 0 -55px;
    padding: .5em 5px;
    background: #006;
    color: #fff;
}

.hover_image:hover .overlay {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKXgw/

You may need to add some JavaScript to make `.hover_image:hover` work in earlier versions of IE, which didn’t support `:hover` on anything except links.

If you can’t have a fixed width/height, it’ll be a lot tricker to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Things aren't really clear to me, any way you can play with the CSS/style of the element to work around on this.

To center an element you can set the `top` and `left` by `50%` where its position is set to `absolute`. Then set the `margin-top` the half size of its height in negative, and the `margin-left` the half size of its width in negative.

To place the div in top of the image, its `z-index` must be higher than the image. But first the image must have the higher `z-index` until its not rolled-over.

To show the div on top of the image change the `z-index` of the image lower then the `div`. Using hover or onMouseOver event. There other ways of doing this, base on your needs.

See jsfiddle in [action](http://jsfiddle.net/46CUk/)

Comment: In Chrome I’m getting a bit of flickering when my mouse moves over the `<div>` that’s on top of the image.

Comment: I see, as an alternative way see Paul code, or see the updated jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/46CUk/1/ also as Paul mentioned about :hover as an alternative to `hover` try this example http://jsfiddle.net/rKJv9/1/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use z-index property with absolute positioning to place the div on top of the image. Since you want this to be hidden, set the "display" property in css to "none".
2. The second part of your question can be accomplished by using a javascript function that you can call onmouseover [ http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp ]. All the function would have to do is change the "display" property of the element from "none" to "block".

Comment: @line-o : that's one nice looking bandwagon you have there